# Iterate through a CSV File to store a var in javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a CSV File which looks like this

```
IDNumber,Year,Email,Name
1234,4,foo@foo.com,Foo Foo
1234,4,foo@foo.com,Foo Foo
```

Say I read the file from here

```
file.ReadFromFile('D:/Programs/POS/members.csv');
```

And I would like to store each line in these vars

```
var IDNumber;
var Year;
var Email;
var Name;
```

Before running some methods from an API im working with.

How do I go about populating these vars once then looping through each one again?

Comment: Is this using a file upload or download? You can't read directly from the disk within the browser. For instance, your comment about ReadFromFile just doesnt exist (in the way you describe)

Comment: Use the split() function with ','

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try external JS "papaparse.js". In below example you will find that parsed data from csv is available in data variable and it becomes an array of objects with proper property name so you can access data with proper OOPs way e.g. if first column in your csv is city then you can get value of first row first column with data[0].city

```
<script src="./papaparse.min.js"></script>
<script src="./jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

var data;
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
var file = evt.target.files[0];

Papa.parse(file, {
  header: true,
  dynamicTyping: true,
  complete: function(results) {
    data = results;
  }
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#csv-file").change(handleFileSelect);
});
</script>

<input type="file" id="csv-file" name="files"/>
```

Click [here](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/parsing-local-csv-file-with-javascript-papa-parse/) to understand more.
Hope this helps you.